# Query on WCF publish subscribe service

Tags: wcf

just asking a general question. I am currently developing a WCF publish subscribe service. why is it that sometimes my publisher is able to publish multiple times with no error and sometimes there is a time out exception caused by it? The error that it would give is

> The message could not be transferred within the allotted timeout of 00:01:00. There was no space available in the reliable channel's
>   transfer window. The time allotted to this operation may have been a
>   portion of a longer timeout.